# problem with rebol vid panel and offset 0x0

Tags: user-interface, layout, rebol

This doesn't work

```
panel1.layout: layout [
  offset: 0x0
  yuml-image: image img
]

panel2.layout: layout [
  offset: 0x0
  area (yuml-command0) yellow
]

panelbuttons.layout: layout [

    button "Save" [request-save]
    button "Refresh" [request-refresh]
    button "Quit" [quit]

]

Main: layout [
  panel1: box 640x300 white
  return
  panelbuttons: box 640x20
  return
  panel2: box 640x180 yellow
]

panel1/pane: panel1.layout
panel2/pane: panel2.layout
panelbuttons/pane: panelbuttons.layout

view/title/options center-face Main "askuml.com" [no-border]
```

I just wanted the equivalent of this:

```
Main: layout [
    offset: 0x0
    yuml-image: image img
    return
    across
    button "Save" [request-save]
    button "Refresh" [request-refresh]
    button "Quit" [quit]
    return
    area (yuml-command0) yellow
]
```

Also why do I have a border whereas I asked offset 0x0 see the ugly grey border below:
[alt text http://askuml.com/files/2010/07/uml-online-tool.gif](http://askuml.com/files/2010/07/uml-online-tool.gif)

Update: now I have this ugly window
[alt text http://askuml.com/files/2010/07/vid-ugly.gif](http://askuml.com/files/2010/07/vid-ugly.gif)

see http://askuml.com/blog/yuml-use-case-desktop-client/

I updated the code now I can't see the (even your :)) buttons:

[image]

Comment: I'd venture the ugly window is to do with directional flow. Things go down by default, so your main layout should be `[origin 0 <panel> <panel> <panel>]` (with <panel> short for your panel defs).  For your buttons, they go across, so `[origin 5x10 space 5 across <btn> <btn> <btn>]` (using `btn` instead of `button` you get *my* button images :)

Comment: Of course, if you wanted to do it all in one, it'd be something like this: `[origin 0 space 6 <image> across pad 6 <btn> <btn> <btn> below <area>]` - directional flow in VID is a fickle beast, but it'll get you there. Just don't even think about resizing (save it for another day).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your first instinct was correct, but would modify it thus:

```
Main: layout [
    origin 0 space 6
    yuml-image: image img 600x400
    across pad 6
    btn "Save" [request-save]
    btn "Refresh" [request-refresh]
    btn "Quit" [quit]
    below
    area (yuml-command0) yellow 600x200
]
```

If you really need to break up the panels, let the 'panel style do the heavy lifting:

```
image-panel: [
    yuml-image: image 600x400 img
]

btn-panel: [
    across origin 6 space 6
    btn "Save" [request-save]
    btn "Refresh" [request-refresh]
    btn "Quit" [quit]
]

area-panel: [
    area yellow 600x200
]

main: layout [
    origin 0 space 0
    panel image-panel
    panel btn-panel
    panel area-panel
]
```

Comment: thanks, this works but I don't understand what is panel : where is it in official doc: I can only see pane ?

Comment: Not sure where it's referenced in the docs (it is name-dropped). There's this though: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/REBOL_Programming/Language_Features/VID#Panels

Comment: OK thank you will read it. I can't see it in the doc here http://www.rebol.com/docs/view-face-content.html or am I mistaken ? It is very confusing that such important thing would not be mentionned in official doc.

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
layout [
    origin 0x0
    ...
]
```

You also have `space 0x0` and `backcolor 238.234.221` to dispense with the grey. I'm partial to changing the area edge as well - `area edge [size: 1x1 effect: none]`

Some other options: `layout/tight [...]` (space and origin 0), `layout/origin [...] 0x0`.

`view/options [no-border]` refers to the OS window.  Any `set-word!` in the layout dialect specifically refers to assigning a word to the subsequent style.

Comment: Thanks for all options will try all. But currently I can't even make work origin 0x0: it says 0x0 misplaced. And return doesn't work either see http://askuml.com/blog/yuml-use-case-desktop-client/

Comment: view layout/offset [btn "test"] 0x0 ;this should work as offset is a refinement for layout function.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
w: layout/size [backcolor red btn "test"] 300x300
v: layout/tight [box blue 100x100]
append w/pane v
view w
```

or use insert instead of append to put the face behind of others:

```
insert w/pane v
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm stupid I don't understand how to apply your code to my use case :)

Comment: may be I'm stupid and misunderstood your question :) I tried to show you to add a layout into another one with offset 0x0. So you may apply this to your case. Note that the second layout (which is 'v) is tight.

Answer (score 1):

Panel is just a layout, nothing else.
You can create layouts and adds them to another layout's pane, or just use panel style.

http://www.rebol.com/how-to/subpanels.html

```
view layout [backcolor yellow size 200x200 origin 0x0 space 0x0 b: panel red [btn "test" lbl "Test"] return panel blue [btn "x" lbl "rest" lbl "x"]]
>> ? b
== B is an object of value:
type            word!     face      ;<--- just a face
offset          pair!     0x0
size            pair!     36x49
span            none!     none
pane            block!    length: 2 ;<--- btn & lbl
...
```

Comment: I thought I did in the 1st place but will look at panel again.